# How to hook up my XML file for axios get method locally

Tags: reactjs, axios

Trying to hook up my XML file so it can be used in an array for an image gallery but I get this error in the log

```
GET http://localhost:3001/src/images.xml 404 (Not Found)
```

Code:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('./src/images.xml')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

XML file:

```
{
      url: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1988681/pexels-photo-1988681.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=woman-s-face-1988681.jpg&fm=jpg' ,
      description: 'This is image 1',
  },
```

Comment: For one thing, that's **not** XML

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat obvious that you are trying to preload an image with an axios call on component mount, but otherwise the question is not too clear. you should elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do and how.

That said, i think, as jonsharpe say, what you call an XML file is actually just an object with some values. Unless you have specified the `axios.baseurl` somewhere in your code that you are not sharing, your axios call won't work:

1. It expects a url of the type you have in your object (`https://images.pexels.com/photos/1988681/pexels-photo-1988681.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=woman-s-face-1988681.jpg&fm=jpg`)

Like so:

```
axios.get('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1988681/pexels-photo-1988681.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=woman-s-face-1988681.jpg&fm=jpg')
.then(resp => console.log(resp.data))
```

Perhaps you want to reformat your call so that that url is called. The XML you are after might actually be in the response ( in `.then(res => res.data)`) if the call is successful. You will have to decode the file that the api responds with or save it somehow.